# Excel VBA Find Row, copy contents, paste in next sheet then delete original data

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working to identify rows in sheet 1 that are not blank in column A and don't have a Y or L in column V. Then I need to copy the contents of that row, then paste values to an open row on the next worksheet.  Lastly, I need to clear contents on the original sheet for that row.  I'm getting stuck when it comes time to paste. Error 1004 - Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed.  I appreciate any help.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Sub EndMove()

Dim rowCount As Long, i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
ws.Range("A11").Select
rowCount = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
Application.ScreenUpdating = False: Application.EnableEvents = False
Call ShowAllRecords
For i = 11 To rowCount
    If ws.Range("V" & i) <> "y" And ws.Range("V" & i) <> "l" Then
        If ws.Range("A" & i) <> "" Then

Dim rowCount2 As Long, j As Long
Dim sRng As Range
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1)
Dim wAct As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim End_Row As Long

Set wAct = ws
Set sRng = ws.Range("V" & i)

If Not IsDate("01 " & wAct.Name & " 2017") Or wAct.Name = "Dec" Then MsgBox "Not applicable for this sheet.": Exit Sub
If ActiveSheet.Index = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count Then MsgBox "This is the last worksheet cannot move forward.": Exit Sub


wAct.unprotect

With ws2
    .unprotect

If rowCount2 = "1" Then

        For j = 11 To Rows.Count
        If .Range("A" & j) = "" Then
            End_Row = j
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Else

End If
    wAct.Range("A" & sRng.row & ":AD" & sRng.row + sRng.Rows.Count - 1).Copy
    .Range("A" & End_Row).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    wAct.Range("A" & sRng.row & ":AD" & sRng.row + sRng.Rows.Count - 1).ClearContents
    .Range("A1000").Value = End_Row
    .protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
End With

wAct.protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowFiltering:=True

Application.CutCopyMode = False


        End If
      End If
Next i
Application.EnableEvents = True: Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Call FilterBlanks
MsgBox "Move Complete"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you quickly record a Macro and perform the Copy/Paste yourself manually, stop recording the Macro and goto VB Editor (Alt+F11) and check the code in the Module vs what your code looks like?

Comment: I got similar code but the same result.

Comment: What line are you getting the error on?

Comment: .Range("A" & End_Row).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats is where the error is.

Comment: You need to identify the worksheet you are pasting on.

Comment: I thought I was with the "With ws2"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is no line in your code that would assign value to rowCount2. So when you check it in code below it gives always false and therefore skips this part

```
If rowCount2 = "1" Then

        For j = 11 To Rows.Count
        If .Range("A" & j) = "" Then
            End_Row = j
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Else
```

but that part is essential as it is the only part where `End_Row` is assigned value. So then when you try to do this `.Range("A" & End_Row)` there is nothing in `End_Row`. Set up a breakpoint on that line and check Locals screen for End_Row to make sure it is this.